# Efficiently storing pairwise samples as TFRecords

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tfrecord, tpu

I have a neural network which takes input in the form `(positive_document, negative_document)`. The input has to come from a TFRecordDataset since I want the model to be trained on a TPU. I am using a pairwise hinge loss.

**The problem**:

I end up storing duplicate data in the TFRecord. For example, the `TFExample`s stored on disk would be:

```
(posdoc_1, negdoc_1),

(posoc_1, negdoc_2),
.
.
(posodoc_1, negdoc_n)
(posdoc_2, negdoc_1),
(posdoc_2, negdoc_2),
.
```

Here `posdoc_1` and `posdoc_2` needlessly repeated.

**An idea for a solution**

The problem could be alleviated to an extend if I can store the `TFExample`s as:

```
(posdoc_1_id, negdoc_1_id)
(posdoc_1_id, negdoc_2_id)
.
.
```

It would be very cheap to store the IDs, and hopefully I can convert them to actual doc representation during training. Something like:

```
for pos_id, neg_id in id_tfrecords:
    posdoc = data_tfrecords[pos_id]
    negdoc = data_tfrecords[neg_id]
```

Where `id_tfrecords` contains  `(posid, negid)` pairs and `data_tfrecords` contains actual document representations

The above clearly won't work (`TFRecordDataset` is not subscriptable to begin with) for a variety of reasons, but now you know what I have in mind.

**What I have already tried**

For datasets that would fit in memory, I wrote `(posid, negid)` pairs to disk and maintained a tensor in memory that would give me the document representation. This more or less like an `EmbeddingLayer` in keras/pytorch. For example, this would be how I convert a training triplet to actual representation:

```
for posid, negid in training_data:
    pos_doc = docid_to_doc[posid] # docid_to_doc is a tensor. Assume docid is an index into this tensor
    .
    .
```

I quickly ran into problems:

1. Apparently a tensor can't be more than 2GB in memory.
2. I tried using `tf.Keras.layers.Embedding` initialized with a custom mapping, but that only works for converting `idx`s to vectors. I want an `idx` to be converted into a 2D matrix.

**The end goal is to**:

1. Save disk space on GCS by not storing duplicate docs.
2. Cut down the time it takes to create the tfrecord

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm a bit confused: do you have a tfrecord and you have problems extracting data from it or do you have data that you want to store in a tfrecord? if so, in what format the data is currently stored?

Comment: I have data that is stored as a TF Record. It's just that I end up storing duplicates of the same sample, and that takes up too much space on my GCS bucket :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save some space if put all negdoc in one tfrecord
(posdoc_1, (negdoc_1,negdoc_2,...,negdoc_n))
and sample negdoc randomly during record parse.
This is a best solution I found for now

One more variant is storing docs as individual files and using tf.io.read_file .
But it works very slow on TPU